# proper statistical test to check differences

Tags: statistics

I have $3$ replicas for a value in different individuals. Each of these values are ratios $\frac{a}{b}$, and $a$ and $b$ are means from $n=20$ sample pool each. Thus there are $3$ times each ratio $\frac{a}{b}$ for each individual. When comparing for differences is student $t$-test correct?

Comment: Perhaps this question is more appropriate at stats.stackexchange.com?